# How to solve "Error: /bin/sh: py: command not found"?

Tags: komodo

I have just installed `Komodo` on Mac and attempted to create a Run Command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>). It seems that I followed the instructions and did everything correct but once I use the command to run a code, the error occurred:

> Error /bin/sh: py: command not found appears.

Can anyone please help me with this? 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you install Python?

Comment: Yes, I did, but previously I used Python 3.4. and now installed Python 3.6. I didn't uninstall Python 3.4 though, can it be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't recognize the "py" command. Install python for mac: [Python Releases for Mac](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/).

After that you type in the terminal "**python --version**" and there should be a output like this: "**Python X.X.X.X**".

If this doesn't works, try to uninstall all previous versions.

Comment: Thank you, I actually had Python 3.4.3 Installed, but now I uninstalled it and there is only latest Python 3.6.5 Installed from the Python Release for Mac. But for some reason the command is not working still....

Comment: Another thing. I installed Python 3.6.5  and Komodo on my computer which is operated by Windows and ran this command on the code:   import platform

print('This is python version {}'.format(platform.python_version())). And Command output is terrifying : ‘Ё­в ЄбЁзҐбЄ п ®иЁЎЄ  ў Ё¬Ґ­Ё д ©« , Ё¬Ґ­Ё Ї ЇЄЁ Ё«Ё ¬ҐвЄҐ в®¬ . I am afraid that  it is Russian language and do not understand why everything goes so wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting to learn Python via Komodo too.

I'm using a Mac and had the same issue. I replaced "py" with "python3" in the command line and it worked for me.

ps: I'm currently on python 3.7.3